# How to get csvkit to recognise long ASCII lines?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, python, ascii

I am using Ubuntu and [I downloaded this CSV file](https://t.co/l5NL2P9miW), which `file` tells me is encoded like:

```
ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

However, when I pass `csvcut -e ASCII datafile`, I get:

```
Your file is not "utf-8" encoded. Please specify the correct encoding with the -e flag. Use the -v flag to see the complete error.
```

and when I pass `csvcut -e ASCII datafile`, I get:

```
Your file is not "ASCII" encoded. Please specify the correct encoding with the -e flag.
```

(Neither capitalisation nor copy-pasting the exact `file` output improves this.)

---

The complete error (`-v`) looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/csvcut", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('csvkit==0.9.2', 'console_scripts', 'csvcut')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/csvkit-0.9.2-py2.7.egg/csvkit/utilities/csvcut.py", line 64, in launch_new_instance
    utility.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/csvkit-0.9.2-py2.7.egg/csvkit/utilities/csvcut.py", line 53, in main
    for row in rows:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/csvkit-0.9.2-py2.7.egg/csvkit/unicsv.py", line 51, in next
    row = next(self.reader)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 535, in next
    return type(self).__next__(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/csvkit-0.9.2-py2.7.egg/csvkit/unicsv.py", line 35, in __next__
    return next(self.reader).encode('utf-8')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 615, in next
    line = self.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 530, in readline
    data = self.read(readsize, firstline=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 477, in read
    newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your payload is neither ASCII nor UTF-8 encoded. You can quickly find the non-ASCII bits:

```
awk '/[^\x00-\x7F]/{ print NR ":", $0 }' data.csv | less
```

You'll see things like `Briarcliffe College�??Patchogue` in a UTF-8 encoded terminal emulator, suggesting that this is not a UTF-8 encoded file. And the first guess of encoding? ISO 8859-1, Western European. Let's test:

```
# piping to /dev/null to suppress printing and speed up processing (printing to tty is slow)
csvcut -e iso-8859-1 data.csv >/dev/null
```

No error this time, voila!